# The url "/testform" does not match any handlers

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine

Hello iam trying to make a form that recieves an input from the user and view it on a web page using python on google app engine this the yaml file content

```
application: myapp
version: alpha-001
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  script: home.app
```

home file's content

```
import webapp2
form = """
<form action="/testform">
<input name='q'>
<input type='submit'>
</form>
"""
class Mainpage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
     def get(self):
         self.response.out.write(form)
class TestHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
     def get(self):
         q = self.request.get('q')
         self.response.out.write(q)
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/',Mainpage),('/testform',TestHandler)],debug=True)
```

and this gives me an error

```
The url "/testform" does not match any handlers.
```

i want to know where is the mistake

Comment: Can I ask you what means "home file's content"?
How you provide a "home.app" ?
I mean, is it _main.py_ or ... whatever ? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the app.yaml

```
handlers:
- url: /
  script: home.app
```

The only url that is handled is `/`. You want home.app to handle all urls, I suppose, in that case change `/` to `.*`, like this:

```
handlers:
- url: .*
  script: home.app
```

Or if you want them seperately you could also do

```
handlers:
- url: /
  script: home.app
- url: /testform
  script: home.app
```

Comment: @MohamedRamzyHelmy please consider to mark this answer as Accepted if it has solved your problem.